# Neo4j won't elect a different master after deadlock

Tags: neo4j

I received the following error from neo4j while our app was running a cypher query.

```
Error: HTTP Error 400 when running the cypher query against neo4j.ForsetiClient[43] 
can't acquire ExclusiveLock{owner=ForsetiClient[42]} on NODE(922), because holders 
of that lock are waiting for ForsetiClient[43]. Wait list:ExclusiveLock[ForsetiClient[42] 
waits for []]
```

This is the second time this has happened to us and I am not sure how to prevent this from happening again. We have never received these error in our development environment so thats why it is a little weird.

Another thing since this has happened if I take done the current master in the cluster none of the other instances in the cluster will become the master which is a major problem. I need to get this fixed quickly any help would be great.

We are using Neo4j 2.1.4 in HA mode.